# How do I automate comparison of two external listboxes in Windows?

Tags: windows, listbox, automation, ui-automation

I've got a super tedious task to do for work that I'm hoping to get some guidance on semi-automating.

We've got a listbox in one program with a few hundred entries. I need to compare that against another listbox in a web app and figure out which values are missing or extra. I don't have access to the code from either.

Any advice on the best way to accomplish that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of problem, you could try using a single Python script that fetches and compares your data.

For the web app portion, you can use [Selenium webdriver](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) - there are a lot of other ways to retrieve your web content (another Python web client library, or the curl command-line program), but webdriver should give you access to the contents of the listbox quite easily.

And for the Windows GUI app portion, you can try using [pywinauto](https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/), [swapy](https://code.google.com/p/swapy/), or go directly to the [MS UI Automation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation) framework.

You could of course approach this with a different language, but I feel Python gives you the best of both worlds (web and native Windows app automation) without too much fuss. It can be nice being able to perform both types of tasks from one script.